# local JSON Data is not viewing on the html page in ionic 5

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I just wanted to print the JSON data from my local **.json** file, I am getting the values of the JSON in console, but it is not printing on the HTML page

**home.page.ts**

```
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  cats:any;
  constructor(public http:HttpClient) {
    this.loadData();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    
  }

  loadData(){
    let data:Observable<any>
    data = this.http.get('assets/backend/db.json');
    data.subscribe(result => {
      this.cats = result;
      console.log(this.cats);
    },
    (err) => {
      alert('failed loading json data');
   });
  }
}
```

**home.page.html**

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let cat of cats">
   <ion-card>
      <ion-card-header>
         <ion-card-title>Name: {{cat.AltName}}</ion-card-title>
         <ion-card-subtitle>Origin: {{cat.Origin}}</ion-card-subtitle>
         <ion-card-subtitle>Average LifeSpan: {{cat.Averagelife}}</ion-card-subtitle>
      </ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-content>
         <img src={{cat.url}} alt="">
         Breed Description: {{cat.BreedDesc}}
      </ion-card-content>
   </ion-card>
</ion-item>
```

**I am getting this in console**

```
animals: Array(9)
0: {AltName: 'Longhair or Persian Longhair', Origin: 'Iran', Averagelife: '12-17 years', BreedDesc: 'Long haired breed of cat that has a short round fa…a thick coat , large eyes and a shortened muzzle.', url: 'https://troubleandtrix.com/media/3kzp0xhw/persian-…crop&width=1238&height=640&rnd=132521132574070000'}
1: {AltName: 'American Burmese, British Burmese', Origin: 'Thailand', Averagelife: '10-17 years', BreedDesc: 'Appears in 2 forms – American and British. The Bri… ones are broader and shorter with a flat muzzle.', url: 'https://www.purina.co.uk/sites/default/files/2021-02/CAT%20HERO_0005_Burmese.jpg'}
2: {AltName: 'Scot Fold, Lops, Folds', Origin: 'Scotland', Averagelife: '11- 15 years', BreedDesc: 'It is a medium sized cat weighing 4-6 kg. The coat…or short-haired and ears can be normal or folded.', url: 'https://d17fnq9dkz9hgj.cloudfront.net/breed-upload…cottish-fold-detail.jpg?bust=1535567146&width=355'}
3: {AltName: 'Bobbed tail cat', Origin: 'United States', Averagelife: '11- 15 Years', BreedDesc: 'These have a short to medium built body with short…Ears are medium sized and eyes are almond shaped.', url: 'https://d17fnq9dkz9hgj.cloudfront.net/breed-upload…American-Bobtail-01.jpg?bust=1539031086&width=355'}
4: {AltName: 'Bengoli Cat', Origin: 'United States', Averagelife: '14-16 Years', BreedDesc: 'Bengal cats are a hybrid of the Asian Leopard Cat …tern and swirly marbled. They have a white belly.', url: ''}
5: {AltName: 'Ankara', Origin: 'Turkey', Averagelife: '12- 18 years', BreedDesc: 'These have long silky coats with round bodies. They are intelligent, playful and loyal with humans.', url: 'https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/bengal-cat-pi…=0&h=fSyuzbgVaj1-ndIhUJq1R2WqE2UveUUeA4iFADdt1CE='}
6: {AltName: 'Spangle', Origin: 'California', Averagelife: '9-16 years', BreedDesc: 'This breed looks similar to a leopard in appearanc…a spotted muscular body  with large whisker pads.', url: 'https://allaboutcats.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/The-California-Spangled-Cats.jpg'}
7: {AltName: 'Mau', Origin: 'Egypt', Averagelife: '13-16 Years', BreedDesc: 'They are slender and muscular cat that are loyal t…egs are comparatively shorter than the hind legs.', url: 'https://vetstreet.brightspotcdn.com/dims4/default/…0568d634f%2Ffile%2FEgyptian-Mau-2-645mk062211.jpg'}
8: {AltName: 'Sacred Birman, Sacred Cat of Burma', Origin: 'France', Averagelife: '12-16 Years', BreedDesc: ' It is a domestic cat breed having medium sized an…that are sapphire blue in color and a roman nose.', url: 'https://st4.depositphotos.com/1004592/24111/i/600/…ck-photo-birman-kitten-front-white-background.jpg'}
length: 9
```

This is the Error which I am getting in the console :

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'
> of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
> Arrays.

Comment: You have verified that `cats` is an array? What does the console log produce?

Comment: `this.cats = result;` result is a response object here. You should extract the data from it. (use `result.data()` or `result.json()`)

Comment: @MaxXx1313 HttpClient creates a generic object out of the response. No `result.json()` needed.

Comment: ok, then we need `this.cats = JSON.parse(result);` =)

Comment: I have updated in the question , what is the output of console log, please check it @AT82

Comment: @MaxXx1313 No, as said, Angular creates a generic object out of the response, no need to parse it either. Please read: https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: I got this error after doing this.cats = JSON.parse(result); 
ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
@MaxXx1313 please check this out

Comment: Please try  '''let cat of cats.animals'''

Comment: Yes, Siddharth is correct, as you can see your array is inside the `animals` property of your response.

Comment: whenever I try to run the program with commenting on the HTML part I get no errors and get all data from JSON in the console but after uncommenting, it gives me an error I guess the problem is with the HTML code in 'ngFor' as the error describes in the question 
@AT82

Comment: ohh it worked  thanks for helping out all of you guys and @SiddharthS.

Comment: Yes, as your response is **NOT** an array, it's an object where there is an array called `animals`.

Comment: yeah I understood it now thanks 